# Avoid gradle cache for the snapshot versions

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am working with SNAPSHOT versions of some libraries in Android Studio.

The problem is that Gradle seems to use a **cached version** of these libraries and **doesn't redownload the new updated** snapshot version.

I tried to use something like this in my gradle script, but it doens't work.

```
dependencies {
    compile ('myGroupId:myArtifactId:X.Y.Z-SNAPSHOT'){
        changing=true
    }
}
```

The only workaround that seems to work is to delete the `~/.gradle/caches` directory and then resync the project in Android Studio.
Of course it is not a good solution.

How can we work with snapshot versions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try adding this to your gradle script:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.cacheChangingModulesFor 0, 'seconds'
}
```

More info:
http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html

Comment: Just a heads-up that this causes all your dependencies to be refreshed on every build/gradle sync which might drastically increase build time. As dependencies do not tend to change every few seconds I recommend using a manual trigger as shown in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29747193/288980). Your build-server can then be configured to use this trigger on every build.

Comment: I think changing modules should only include snapshot versions, rather than refreshing all dependencies like @Mannaz 's option?

Answer (score 19):

You can also use the gradle parameter [`--refresh-dependencies`](https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:cache_refresh)

> The --refresh-dependencies option tells Gradle to ignore all cached entries for resolved modules and artifacts. A fresh resolve will be performed against all configured repositories, with dynamic versions recalculated, modules refreshed, and artifacts downloaded. ...

---

I for myself created a new gradle run command called *refresh* which calls 
`./gradlew --refresh-dependencies clean`

[image: run debug configuration screenshot]

Comment: This script works well (+1). In any case I prefer the other answer because in a team it seems more comfortable and suitable.

Comment: Doesn't that also refresh non-snapshot dependencies?